# How to use Props to jQuery in React component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I hope you understand this simple example.

I tried to change the background color of my HTML element on first render by handling it in React Component with a bit help of jQuery.

This is the code inside my React Component (the **props** is passed from **state of Parent Component**):

```
class QuoteBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  
  
  componentDidMount() {
    $('#root').css('background-color', this.props.color); 
    $('#text').css('color', this.props.color);
    $('#author').css('color', this.props.color);
  }

  render() {   
    return (
      <div>
          <div id="quote-box" className="quote-box">
            <div className="quote">
              <span id="text" class="quote-text">{this.props.quote}</span>
            </div>
            <div id="author" className="quote-author">
              <span>- {this.props.author}</span>
            </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The code inside `componentDidMount()` seem doesn't recognize the `this.props.color`. But if change to `$('#root').css('background-color', 'green');` it's immediately change the background to green on first render.

But in `render()` it recognize another props.

So what did I do wrong? Is there a way to target HTML element using jQuery inside React?

Comment: you shouldn't be trying to mix jQuery with React. jQuery uses an imperative code style and React a declarative one - they don't mix very well. There's nothing you need jQuery for if you are using React.

Comment: as for the actual question - check the props you're passing to this component from the parent. You don't show this, but I'm pretty certain there won't be a "color" value there (or it won't be a string that's a recognised CSS color - remember that hex colors need a # at the start of the string).

Comment: @RobinZigmond actually, it works when I directly inline style it on HTML element inside react component. Like this:  `<div style={{'background': this.props.color}};>`

Comment: @RobinZigmond so it's no use to use jQuery in React?

Comment: I hesitate to say "no use", but I've yet to see a reasonable use case. For what you're doing here, just set the style directly as you've already indicated in your last comment. Unless of course you *want* to have the color change only after the first render, but you can do that with state instead.

Comment: I cannot see why it would work with `this.props.color` directly in the `style` attribute but not when you set it with jQuery in componentDidMount - but I can't see what your props are or what else might be going on.

Comment: You can change the CSS of a div in React by using `<div className={this.props.somestyle}>hello world</div>`. And then pass the `somestyle` css class in the props. So that's why you don't need `$('#root').css()`.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely happens, because on the first render the `props.color` is not set. It is most likely, set on the parent element causing a re-render of the `QuoteBox`, which will not run the `componentDidMount` which is only run on the first render.

Besides the fact that you should not mix jQuery DOM manipulation with React, just to test your scenario, try using `componentDidUpdate` instead and it will most likely fix your issue.